# Creating a simple Android fragment with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm an experienced developer, but new to Android programming, and I'm a bit stumped. I started off with the Android Studio Navigation Drawer standard project template. I managed to implement a simple list of items in one of the fragments (Gallery Fragment), and do something when a button is pressed. So when the button is pressed, I want it to drill down to a new screen. Should be pretty simple one would think, but I've read a dozen Android fragment tutorials, and I can't get anything to happen.

So I've created the new fragment that I want to activate:

```
package tech.iconultra.ui.gallery

import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import tech.iconultra.R

private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"
class IconPackGalleryFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private var listener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.icon_pack_gallery, container, false)
        return root
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    fun onButtonPressed(uri: Uri) {
        listener?.onFragmentInteraction(uri)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        listener = null
    }

    interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            IconPackGalleryFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

And a simple layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/icon_pack_gallery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="Name" />

        <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <TableLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <TableRow
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </TableLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

but I'm stumped as to what incarnation can activate them.
I've tried this:

```
                                val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = activity!!.supportFragmentManager
                                fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.apply {
                                    add(0, IconPackGalleryFragment(), "aaaaa")
                                    commit()
                                }
```

and nothing happens. I've tried:

```
                                val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = activity!!.supportFragmentManager
                                fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.apply {
                                    replace(R.id.installed_app_list, IconPackGalleryFragment(), "aaaaa")
                                    commit()
                                }
```

(R.id.installed_app_list is the fragment I'm calling it from).
I've tried replacing R.id.installed_app_list with various other layouts, but I'm baffled what I am supposed to pass here in the case of the standard navigation drawer template project. This code makes the app crash with the error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
```

----- EDIT  ------
I've found that this makes the fragment appear:

```
  fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.apply {
      add(android.R.id.content, IconPackGalleryFragment(), "aaaaa")
      addToBackStack("aaaaa")
      commit()
  }
```

There's some problems though: 1) the fragment seems to have an invisible background, despite the fragment itself saying that its background should be white with a 100% alpha.  2) Pressing back doesn't take you to the previous screen. Instead, the first press takes you to the home nav screen (not the nav screen that launched that fragment) AND with the fragment still appearing in front of it (!). A second press on the back button then removes the fragment.'

It's progress I guess, but still confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, apparently the android navigation drawer template uses the navigation component, and that means I have to learn how to use the navigation designer on mobile_navigation.xml, add a new screen in there, make a link between my previous screen and my new screen, and then when I want to activate it I call the following, passing the id of the link between my screens.

`findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_gallery_to_iconPackGalleryFragment)`

After doing that, it works. I still need to learn and understand when to use the fragmentmanager, and when to use the navigation controller, but it seems like in this case, use the navigation controller, not the fragment manager.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
val fragmentManager = (activity as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager
val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
val fragment = IconPackGalleryFragment()
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_iconpackgallery, fragment)
fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

and in the xml file add:

```
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_iconpackgallery"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

where do you need it.

Comment: According to the documentation for transaction.add, the first argument is the container you want to put the fragment in. You are asking me to put the fragment into itself. This causes the program to crash with "No view found". Intuitively, the API wouldn't make sense to pass the fragment id AND the fragment object, because the fragment object already knows how to create (inflate) the fragment layout with its id, the only question is how to attach it to the existing program.

Comment: @xpusostomos Thank you for your reply. Did you create the view for the `Fragment` IconPackGalleryFragment() in `res/layout`?
In `res/layout` you need to create the Fragment view `res/layout/fragment_iconpackgallery.xml` and in the `Activity` where this Fragment lives you need to add the FrameLayout in the activities xml file.

I guess your app crashes because your app is missing the view `res/layout/fragment_iconpackgallery.xml`

Comment: The layout is in res/layout. And the constructor for IconPackGalleryFragment() successfully inflates it. So I don't think the problem is there.